# Vimdiff: Is there a way of knowing if there are differences in the diff files or not?

Tags: vimscript, vimdiff

I am trying to find (in Vim script) if the 2 files open using vimdiff are same or different? Is there a way to do that? (a variable like &diff perhaps?)

Comment: If the files are identical, there is one closed fold displayed on each side. Perhaps you could check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is not to make vim do any work at all: `diff -q` reports if files are different, and `diff -s` if they are the same. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5439382) if you don’t need output, `cmp -s` works.

So in vimscript you might do

```
let l:files = [ get_file_names() ] " left as an exercise
call system('cmp -s ' . join(l:files, ' '))
" do something with v:shell_error
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking for any sort of native solution. Don't want to depend on external programs for better portability. If nothing comes up, will use this :)

Comment: @AnkitJain, I think you *should* depend on external dependencies in this case, because vimdiff is supposed to be used for resolving merge conflicts and such, not calculation stuff. I skimmed through the help docs for vimdiff, and found nothing related to what you want. As I said, it is supposed to be interactive. But if you have constraints to fulfill, then you should be able to build up a vimscript function that ultimately checks itself if contents of two files are same or not. But I doubt you can do it with `vimdiff` itself.

Comment: @klaus you may be able to use the fact that vimdiff folds sections of the file that are the same, but as I learned creating [auto-origami](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami) this kind of fold detection is hard

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, one answer using that approach is provided.

Comment: @klaus I guess I will accept this answer since there is nothing that can be done by Vim itself.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is a very hacky approach. You really should check the result of `diff` using e.g. a custom `diffexpr`. But you asked for it, so here we go:

```
let a=win_getid()|exe "windo let g:diff=(get(g:, 'diff', 1) && foldclosed(1) && foldclosedend(1)==line('$'))"|if g:diff |echomsg 'no differences found' |else |echomsg 'there are some differences!' |endif|call win_gotoid(a)
```

(one line).

This assumes, that all windows are in diff mode and basically checks, whether each window contains only a single folded line.

Comment: As you said this is a hacky. Let me check it out nonetheless and see if this can work. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you asked for it...